# How to get date from mysql +30 days equal to today on php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm very lack of coding, so here my code before (get date from mysql = today --> alert) and I want to get help from y'all to make my code to (get date from mysql + 30 days = today --> alert)

```js
<?php 
                    $periksa=mysql_query("select * from tor where target_tor = curdate()");
                    while($q=mysql_fetch_array($periksa)){  
                        if ($q['target_tor'] = mysql_query("Select Curdate()")){
                            ?>  
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    $('#pesan_sedia').css("color","red");
                                    $('#pesan_sedia').append("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk'></span>");
                                });
                            </script>
                            <?php
                            echo "<div style='padding:10px' class='alert alert-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> PERINGATAN !!  Deadline kontrak <a style='color:red'>". $q['nama_tor']."</a> berakhir hariini!!</div>"; 
                        }
                    }
                    ?>    
                    </p>
```

Comment: **mysql_* functions** are deprecated use  **mysqli_* functions**

Comment: Why two query ? For the same purpose ?

Comment: Hi all, I'm sorry because my coding skill very lack...can you help me using code directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :**  **Warning !!!** `mysql_query, mysql_fetch_array,mysql_connect etc..` extensions were deprecated in `PHP 5.5.0,` and it was removed in `PHP 7.0.0.`

**2nd :** No need mutiple query just select in single query .simple use `date_add()` function

```
select * from tor where date_add(target_tor,INTERVAL 30 DAY )=curdate();
```

**3rd :** Try to use `mysqli_* or PDO`

Comment: Hi JYoThI! I'm trying and error like this 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: mysqli_query expects two parameter first parameter is connection object second parameter is sql query @SeraSera    take a look on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1

Comment: Hi JYoThI!!! BIG THANKSSS ANW...now my code is working :D

Comment: OK thankyou very much :))))

Comment: Glad to help you :)